# Is there a way I can modify icon themes?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, icon-themes

There are currently two icon themes that I like, but I prefer certain icons over others. Is there a way to put certain image files into the different folders and mix the two themes?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a specific method but you can perform this manually.
I changed the "view-app-grid-symbolic" icon by copying the new icon in the theme directory.

```
sudo cp ubuntu-icon.svg /usr/share/icons/Suru/scalable/actions/view-app-grid-symbolic.svg
```

[image: Icon app grid]

After the copy, reload Gnome.

You have to perform the copy and reload at each update of your theme.

Hope this help.